# MSVC 2015 only provides me with linker error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, linker

I am working on a solution with 100+ files. I am using MS Visual Studio 2015 Pro. Compiling it is fine, problems come at link stage.

LINK complains on one of the project's library but only gives me the error number. 
The command line (simplified) used is the following:

```
LINK.exe /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /IMPLIB:C:\\MySolution\\myownlib.lib -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -subsystem:console -MACHINE:X86 -DEBUG -INCREMENTAL /DLL File1.cpp.1.o File2.cpp.1.o File3.cpp.1.o File4.cpp.1.o /OUT:C:\\MySolution\\myownlib.dll
```

The only output I get is the following:

```
File1.cpp.1.o : error LNK2005:

File2.cpp.1.o : error LNK2005:

File3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2005:

File4.cpp.1.o : error LNK2005:

File1.cpp.1.o : error LNK2001:

File2.cpp.1.o : error LNK2001:

File3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2001:

File4.cpp.1.o : error LNK2001:
```

I cannot find any clue as to why the linker does not complains with the duplicated symbols nor the unresolved ones. Since the lib owns more than 80 objects, and nearly all of them is listed, finding the erroneous symbol(s) is like looking for a needle in a haystack!

**EDIT** : I do not compile using the IDE, I use the developer command prompt to build. Migrating the project in Visual Studio is not frankly possible as the program I am working on has never been imported under Visual Studio, we only use the compiler/linker. Moreover, a colleague of mine working on the project does not experience such troubles. It seems that something is going on under my environment...

**EDIT 2** : Full installation repair fixed the problem.

Comment: There's not much to go on here. Are you building it from the command line or the IDE? If you can see which symbols are defined more than once (or undefined) we'd have a clue. What happens if you rebuild (sometimes things go wrong with incremental builds)?

Comment: The environment is very obviously broken. You may have to reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: VS usually come with `setenv.bat`. Be sure you are using it.

Comment: It might be worth comparing the output of `set PATH` with the PC that works

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I did repair the installation and everything went back to normal. Many thanks!